# sass-lint.yml disabled rules are showing as "info"s rather than absent

Tags: visual-studio-code, sass-lint

I've placed a `sass-lint.yml` file in my project to get rid of some of the pesky errors that are thrown. As I add rules I can see that sass-lint is observing them becasue the ignored errors are showing as blue info icons rather than yellow warning icons. Also the green style error underline remains. How can I make these go away instead? The image below should give you an idea of what I'm describing.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently you have to set defaults to `0`, `1`, or `2` rather than `false`. like this:

```
indentation: 
  - 0
empty-line-between-blocks: 
  - 0
property-sort-order: 
  - 0
```

Where:

- 0 turns it off
- 1 sets it as a warning
- 2 sets it to an error

[image]